# PHPMailer Mailer Error: The following From address failed: me@x.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected

Tags: php, phpmailer

Before you classify this post as a duplicate, please note that I've been working on this issue for days and I've reviewed all of the other posts.

```
Previous solution: Use the latest version of PHPMailer.
```

- I've tried PHPMailer 6.2.0, 6.1.8 , 6.1.7 and older versions
- I've tried using the composer and i've also tried using PHPmailer
  without the composer.

Sometimes PHPMailer works and sometimes I get the same error. There's no rhyme or reason. I can run the following script and it works with no error, run it 5 seconds later then it doesn't work, run it again 5 seconds later and it works. What the heck?!

```
require_once("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

also tried:

```
require "PHPMailer3/PHPMailer-6.2.0/src/PHPMailer.php"; 
require "PHPMailer3/PHPMailer-6.2.0/src/SMTP.php"; 
require "PHPMailer3/PHPMailer-6.2.0/src/Exception.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Lets continue:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host      = "10.10.10.38";
$mail->Port      = 25; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = false; 
$mail->SMTPAuth  = false; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

$mail->SetFrom ("me@x.com", "me"); 
$mail->AddReplyTo("me@x.com", "me");

$mail->Subject    = "I need help fixing you";
$mail->AltBody    = "Yes It Worked!"; 
$body ="Yes It Worked!";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);


$mail->AddAddress("x@x.com", "x");


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

**Another Previous** solution: check the from address

- At first i thought this was the solution because my from address was a variable but that's not it! I'm using a static from address.

**Another Previous solution**: the from address is using single quotes but everything else is using double quotes.

- Tried that

I've also tried:

```
$mail->From = "me@x.com";
$mail->FromName = "me@x.com";
```

What else is there to try?

By the way, i'm running PHP 7.3.21 and i'm using an internal SMTP relay server. Please dont suggest using a different email server. I have to get it working with the current server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using looks like it's been copied from a very old example, though I don't think that's the issue here.

```
require_once("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

that file is obsolete and has been omitted from supported PHPMailer versions since 2017.

> I can run the following script and it works with no error, run it 5 seconds later then it doesn't work, run it again 5 seconds later and it works.

This tells you something important – *your script (and PHPMailer) is not the source of the problem*. The most likely explanation is that your mail server, or a firewall between you and the mail server, has some kind of throttling or rate limiting that's preventing you sending all the time, resulting in inconsistent results.

You're also doing this:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```

Since you're trying to *debug an SMTP issue*, don't you think that this might possibly be relevant? Especially since it's [one of the first things referred to in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output) I'm sure you've seen already, and used and described in literally hundreds of answers on here. Your very first step should be to set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` and read what the output says, and post it as part of your question.

Comment: I only gave require_once("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); as an example as to one of the many many actions that i've tried. I just tried https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps and got the same error: 2021-02-08 21:02:54 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2021-02-08 21:02:54 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
The following From address failed: me@x.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected,,,SMTP server error: Called MAIL FROM without being connected SMTP server error: Called MAIL FROM without being connected

Comment: Right, so like I said, this is not a problem with your script  it’s your environment.

Comment: Please update your post so i can close the thread. Like you said, the problem was with the email server. The IT group just fixed it. SMFH

Comment: What I said pretty much lines up with what you found, so I'm not sure what you want me to change?